# Play audio through muliple channels with python

Tags: python, audio, mp3, mixer, python-gstreamer

Is there a way in python to play two different mono mp3 files through the left and right channels?

I have two mp3 files and I want to play one through the left speaker and the other mp3 through the right speaker, programatically in python. Any solution is OK. If it is a cross-platform solution, then great. Does any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

For a simple solution, download and try the `audiere` module.  This will open the first available audio device:

```
import audiere
ds = audiere.open_device()
os = ds.open_array(input_array, sampling_frequency)
os.play()
```

Where your `input_array` should be 2-dim numpy array of floats, you could e.g. decompress your input mp3s into `left` and `right` 1-dim arrays and then use `input_array = np.c_[left, right]`.  Since the data is a raw array you need to specify the `sampling_frequency` of your input.  If they're different lengths you'll need to pad one or the other with zeros.

Comment: Is it a good idea to load the full mp3 file (which can be 4-5mb in size) to an array? Is it possible to load the left and right channels with separate files if we use gstreamer or any other standard python modules?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, but it would probably be a whack more effort than this quick and dirty solution.  Loading the raw data to an array shouldn't be too much of a problem on most machines these days (it would be 100-200MB memory).  Have you considered just writing a shell script to convert your files to mono and then write a new stereo file from the separate channels?